# Calling function whenever full calendar view changes in Angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I am using full calendar in my angular 8 app. Everything is working fine, but I want to call a function whenever the currentView of calendar changes. that is, I want to call a function/event whenever I change its view from month to week, or week to days.

For clarity, I want to detect view template changes (not date range changes). And by detecting it I want to highlight the button of respective current view.

This is my html code.

```
<p-fullCalendar #fc [events]="allEvents" [options]="options"></p-fullCalendar>
```

This is my .ts code

```
this.options = {
      plugins: [dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, interactionPlugin],
      defaultDate: moment().toDate(),
      themeSystem: 'yeti',
      header: {
        left: 'prev,next',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
      }, dateClick: (e) => {
        this.dateClicked(e);
      }, eventClick: (e) => {
        this.eventClicked(e);
      },
    }
```

Comment: You've tagged both fullCalendar 4 and fullCalendar 5. They are different in many ways. Please tag only the version you are actually using - thanks.

Comment: There are two separate things you can detect - changing the view template (e.g. from month to timegrid to list), and changing the date range (i.e. displaying a different set of days on the calendar, regardless of whether the view was also changed). Which one do you actually want? or is it both? What functionality are you looking to achieve by detecting these changes?

Comment: I want to detect view template.
And by detecting it I want to highlight the button of respective current view.

Comment: Ok. See my first comment - which version of fullCalendar are you using? Because the answer is slightly different in each case.

Comment: For v4 you should look at https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/viewSkeletonRender. But for v5 it changed and you should look at https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v5/view-render-hooks

Comment: viewSkeletonRender worked for me.
Thanks!!

Comment: Ok. I've updated your question with only the correct tags. In future please do that yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fullCalendar 4 you can use the [viewSkeletonRender](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/viewSkeletonRender) callback - this runs whenever a new view template is loaded.

```
viewSkeletonRender: function(info)
{
  console.log(info); //replace with whatever code you need.
}
```

**UPDATE**: As per https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v5/upgrading-from-v4 , since v5 this function has been superseded by `viewDidMount`.

Comment: Is it a calendar option or a separate function?

Comment: @Dawid it's a calendar option. You provide the option with a callback function which fullCalendar will then execute whenever the relevant event occurs.

Comment: Yea, I've just checked it, but it only works the first time you change the view, and it doesn't work for changing days / weeks / months with the next / previous buttons. So, for example, if I wanted to get the start and the end date of a current view, it works but only the first time. For the current week, I obtain 1-08.02, but when I click on next / previous nothing changes. Isn't it considered as a view change? If no, how can I react to the change in the day / week / month by means of prev / next?

Comment: @Dawid `it doesn't work for changing days / weeks / months`...yes it's not intended to. It only works when the type of view is changed (e.g. month to timegrid). Changing the date merely changes the date, it doesn't change the view. What are you trying to achieve with this? Why do you need to detect a change of date?

Comment: I want to query a DB for entries that correspond to the current date range of a specific view. If I'm in week 1-07.02, I want to fetch data for that range. If I click on the month view, I want to fetch data for 1-28.02. If I click on next, I fetch data for 1-31.03. If I change to the day view, I get data for 5.02. If I click on previous, I fetch data for 4.02 and so on. Do you know how I can achieve this?

Comment: @Dawid Yes, you can do that, but you need to use the built-in functionality that fullCalendar provides for the purpose. You don't need to detect the date changes yourself, fullCalendar will do that for you. What you do need to do is tell fullCalendar where it should look in order to fetch new events. This can be either a URL where it can download JSON directly, or a callback function where you can customise the fetching process and then return the processed data back to fullCalendar. In both scenarios fullCalendar will provide you with the date range it would like to get events for.

Comment: @Dawid See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed and https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function for details of these two approaches.